# Separate date property from DateTime object

Tags: php, arrays, json

Unable to separate the date property from the DateTime object. What do I do?

I have used the following code:

```
while( $fetch = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt , SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    //echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r($fetch); exit;
    $date=$fetch['Dt_Installment_Date'];
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($date); exit;
}
```

The current output that I am getting is as follows:

```
<pre>DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2019-01-18 00:00:00.000000
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
    )
```

I want to get only the [date] property and nothing else.

Comment: read the documentation of datetime on php.net

Comment: `print_r($date->format('m/d/Y'));`

Comment: you can use ```$fetch->format('r')```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how you can format your DateTime object and convert into a String.

```
// Y : means year , m : means months , d : means days. and you can change format by seperating "/" or using same with "-"
$result = $date->format('Y-m-d');

echo $result;
```

Output is 2019-01-18

Comment: @AkashSaha Have a nice day. You should make a research about function on php.net before asking questions.